# PowerShell with Invoke-Command/PSExec

Tags: powershell, csv, psexec, invoke-command

Let's suppose I have a CSV file named "PCs.csv" with three 'columns' ("name","user","pw").

Now, let's also suppose that I want to run a very simple command on each PC, using the credentials associated with it.

Initially, since Server and Workstation are both using PS 5.0 (and PSRemoting is Enabled), I was testing with `Invoke-Command` and result output was exactly what I wanted (which is exactly the same as if I'd been on the machine running the command).  The problem with this, however...is that I was on the machine.  As the user to whom the credentials powershell was using to run the command belong.  And the results were not evident in the slightest.

Then...I figured I'd use PSExec.  That returns an error stating:

```
psexec.exe : The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:7 char:5
+     & C:\PSTools\PSExec.exe \\$pc.name /accepteula -u $un -p $pc.pw "n ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo           : NotSpecified: (The system cann...file specified.:Strin
   g) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId  : NativeCommandError

Error opening {name=PC01; user=user01; pw=pass01}.name:
```

So, below are the two scripts I used...I just need one of them to work.  In fact, that's a lie...I don't even need one of them to work...if there's something else that will work better, I'm equal opportunity!

**Invoke-Command:**

```
$PCs = Import-Csv "C:\PCs.csv"
ForEach ($pc in $PCs) {
    $un = "DOM\" + $pc.user
    $pw = ConvertTo-SecureString $pc.pw -AsPlainText -Force
    $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($un,$pw)

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc.name -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock {
        cmd.exe /c "net use * /delete /yes"
    }
}
```

**And PSExec:**

```
$PCs = Import-Csv "C:\PCs.csv"
ForEach ($pc in $PCs) {
    $un = "DOM\" + $pc.user  

    & C:\PSTools\PSExec.exe \\$pc.name /accepteula /u $un /p $pc.pw "net use * /delete /yes"
}
```

I'm sure there's something really stupid I'm missing, so I do apologize for that ahead of time.  But, on the bright side - if that is the case, at least we can all have a hearty laugh :)

Comment: What's your intent? To delete all of the user's mapped drives? Sounds like something for Group Policy to me.

Comment: Yes, that's the objective.  And, unfortunately, the person who built/maintained their server/domain up until now must've been incredibly scatter-brained, or something.  Whatever their particular brand of shortcoming, GPO is broken and unreliable.  Sometimes, it will apply...a majority of the time, though, it won't.  So, to avoid hitting each individual workstation, I figured it might be something that can be done quickly via script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no need to disconnect a drive mapping *in use* by a logged on session, you don't need psexec, as you don't need to run the command *in* a user session. Impersonating as the user, and loading the profile is sufficient, because drive mappings get stored by `net use` (in case a drive letter was provided, and the /persistence flag set) in the user specific part of the registry, HKCU (`Get-Childitem -path HKCU:\network` shows the persistent drive mappings, `net use` shows the active drive mappings). To verify this, first I logged on to a session using RDP, and made a drive mapping with the persistent flag. Then I used your  script to remove this drive mapping:

```
$PCs = Import-Csv "C:\PCs.csv"
ForEach ($pc in $PCs) {
    $un = "SSS\" + $pc.user
    "user: $un, password: $($pc.pw)"
    $pw = ConvertTo-SecureString $pc.pw -AsPlainText -Force
    $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($un,$pw)

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc.name -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock {
        whoami /user
        Get-Childitem -path HKCU:\network
        cmd.exe /c "net use * /delete /yes"
        Get-Childitem -path HKCU:\network
    }
}
```

The next time I logged on using RDP, the drive mapping was not created anymore.

Comment: Well, that's just it - nothing seemed to go wrong with the `Invoke-Command`.  It returned the same output as if I had logged on to the target PC, as the desired user, and ran `net use * /delete /yes` - BUT, when I do go log on to the target PC, as the desired user, none of the drive-mappings have been removed.

Comment: @Steve: Was it a an administrator type or a normal user?

Comment: @Steve: never mind, I see the `net use` is not even persistent across several `invoke-command`s. investigating...

Comment: Verified! Thanks, Bart!

So, in order to remove the drive mappings without needing the user to logoff and back on, I'd need to to first get the user's Session ID, and then run the net use command from an interactive psexec session, using the Session ID.

My code-fu is not strong enough for such a task, but a reboot will be required shortly after this command will be run, anyhow.

Comment: Actually, looks like even if I use psexec with -i, the connections will still be there until logoff/logon (in case anyone else can benefit from that information)

Comment: Can you share your psexec code, I can take a look. I would expect that if you run that in the user's session, the user will immediately loose it's drive mapping.

Comment: Sure - Basically just used your working script as the base, and ran it on test machine with my csv only having the test user name/pw (and PC name); Initially, after `$sesh` the next line was `& C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe \\$pc.name /accepteula -u $un -p $pc.pw -i $sesh "net use * /delete /yes"`  But then I was reading somewhere that better results would be had be using `Start-Process -Wait`:

Comment: **I'm apparently just incapable of formatting in comments, so the following goes in the 'ForEach' section**   $sesh = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc.name -Credential 
    $creds -ScriptBlock {
            param($un)
            (Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Select Username,SessionId | Where-Object {$_.UserName -eq $un} | Sort-Object -Unique).SessionId
        } -ArgumentList $un

        $sesh
        Start-Process -Wait -PSPath 'C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe' -ArgumentList '\\$pc.name /accepteula -u $un -p $pc.pw -i $sesh "net use * /delete /yes"'

Comment: oops ... you are right, I see it: A net use * /d /y from a cmd.exe in the same session id, same user, however started from psexec -i, does NOT remove the drive mappings. I need to study this...

Comment: As do I - my understanding just isn't where it needs to be.  The concept of the -i switch could be super useful in other things (like running commands in specific user sessions on an RDS Server)...but now that we've verified it doesn't run the net /delete command as intended on the user/session specified...I'm skeptical of it's capabilities.  If I learn anything, I'll be sure to bring it here.

Comment: I'm a bit closer: Active drive mappings are visible using WinObj (sysinternals): `\Sessions\<sessionid>\DosDevices\<AuthenticationID>\<drive letter>:`. There can be several AuthenticationIDs per session. The LanMan driver symlink for a drive mapping device has the AuthenticationID in its link name (not the sessionid) (see: [WNetAddConnection3 documentation, Remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385418(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Yes, this is what happens: The cmd.exe started by psexec, even in the same sessionId, gets another AuthenticationID, hence the drive mapping shortcuts get stored in different 'folders' under \Sessions\0\Dosdevices\00000000-xxxxxxxx\